# Hosting home page as static site on Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a webapp which is currently serving on `mydomain.com/homepage`. It's a nodeJS based app. I want to only move the homepage part of it to be hosted on a static site on Azure blob storage and the the existing app to serve on `app.mydomain.com`.

So, the plan is to create a static site on Azure Storage and serve it through CDN on a custom domain. However, the Azure page suggests that root domains are not supported. Is there any way to make this work? 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-custom-domain-name?tabs=azure-portal

Or is there a better way to make this kind of change?

Comment: Do you have any questions in my reply?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can map root domain to the Azure CDN profile. With this option, you deliver your content with a custom domain in your URL (`https://mydomainexample.com`) instead of an endpoint name (`https://www.contoso.com/photo.png`). Then it looks like mapping a root domain to the static website endpoint in the Azure Storage

To map a custom domain with HTTPS enabled, you could refer to the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-custom-domain-name?tabs=azure-portal#map-a-custom-domain-with-https-enabled). Especially, add a root domain to the Azure CDN profile, you can [point zone apex to Azure CDN endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-alias#point-zone-apex-to-azure-cdn-endpoints) by using Azure DNS **alias records**. If so, you can host your DNS domains in Azure DNS, you must delegate the domain provider's domain name system (DNS) to an Azure DNS. For more information, see [Delegate a domain to Azure DNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-delegate-domain-azure-dns).

Please note that Pointing a zone apex to CDN endpoints for **Azure CDN from Akamai** is currently not supported. You can select to use other Azure CDN price tier.